# What kind of NSDictionary is this? (plain text kind of like JSON but not quite)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

What format is this http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/vocabwords.txt

I can import it with this code:

```
NSURL *wordURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/vocabwords.txt"];

words = [[NSMutableDictionary    dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:wordURL] retain];
```

i can't find out more about this format without knowing its name and am struggling to find out what it is called :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD) in `NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat` — they're still supported for reading.

Comment: And convenient for when you're writing a plist by hand!